# Understanding Liquibase behavior when one of the changesets fails.

Tags: liquibase

If i have let's say 22 changesets and one of these changesets (say changeset number 10) fails. What is the expected behavior ho liquibase in such case. Will it rollback all previous changesets or leave them executed ?

Comment: A changeSet is like a transaction, once it was successful it's not considered any more.

Comment: In that case do i have to rollback manually?

Comment: This very much depends on your DBMS. If you have a DBMS that supports transactional DDL you should put everything that "belongs together" into a **single** changeset because a changeSet is run inside a transaction (so if one step fails very previous step of that changeSet is automatically rolled back). If you are on a DBMS that does not support transactions with DDL then, you will have to do that manually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if one changeset has 4 statements and the 3rd one fails, in that case would statement 1 and 2 get rolleback automatically?

Comment: Again: that depends on the DBMS you are using. In Postgres they would be rolled back, in Oracle no